# Displaying video file on webpage with laravel

Tags: laravel, video, display

I have a video in the database and also the directory folder. I am trying to display the video on the webpage but I dont see it. Can you help me? heres my code:

```
<div class="" style="border:1px solid blue;"><video height="300" autoplay controls><source  alt="video not playing" src="{{asset ('introvideos/' .Auth::user()->intro_video) }}">
</source>
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: What format of the video do you have? 
Have you checked the browser console or found the file ?

Comment: MP4 fomat and I just checked the console and it tells me Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Why am I getting this?

Comment: you add wrong path to this file

Comment: I did? Then how am I supposed to write the path. Its located in storage_path in a folder called intro video. So how am I supposed to point it to the path?

Comment: show the exact location of the video file and the file that reads it.Also you may try add `storage_parth/introvideos/` to begining of you path

Comment: I did that It's still not working....I've been working on this all day? what is wrong with this?

Comment: The `asset` helper just turns your input into a fully qualified URL (e.g: `asset('introvideos/' . Auth::user()->intro_video)` becomes `https://example.com/introvideos/[...]` which refers to the document root of your project, which is the `public` directory, so it's looking for the `introvideos` directory under `public`. Does your `introvideos` directory exist within the `public` directory?

Comment: Hey, I figured it out!!! Thank you so much for helping me:)